# How to implement profiles in an Android application?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, preferences, profiles

I'm coding an app that uses configurable profiles for different user preferences: many different users will use the same app on the same device.

The problem is that I can't use Android's PreferenceActivity because it just support one user per application.

Is there an easy way to generate the user interface for configuration, or I have to code everything from 0, including the user interface?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> many different users will use the same
>   app on the same device

That seems unusual.

> The problem is that I can't use
>   Android's PreferenceActivity because
>   it just support one user per
>   application.

You might be able to create your own subclass of `PreferenceManager` that uses a different file per person, then return an instance of that in your `PreferenceActivity` in `getPreferenceManager()`.

Comment: It could be an app in a vertical...like perhaps something for a worker in a warehouse.  In which case people across different shifts would use the same device.